# HMAC-SHA256 Algorithm for signature calculation

Tags: java, character-encoding, digital-signature, hmac

I am trying to create a signature using the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm and this is my code.
I am using US ASCII encoding.

```
final Charset asciiCs = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
final Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
final SecretKeySpec secret_key = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(asciiCs.encode("key").array(), "HmacSHA256");
sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
final byte[] mac_data = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(asciiCs.encode("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog").array());
String result = "";
for (final byte element : mac_data)
{
    result += Integer.toString((element & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
}
System.out.println("Result:[" + result + "]");
```

The result that I am getting from the above code is:

```
f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8
```

This is same as to that of shown in the wiki

```
HMAC_SHA256("key", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") = 0x f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8
```

*except* for the `0x`.

I am looking for ideas/comments if I am doing everything right or may be I can improve my code.

Comment: Do you have a *specific* problem or question?

Comment: thank you so much, i've been looking for JUST THAT piece of code for over a day...

Comment: 0x means that the value is hexadecimal, so your result is correct.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The 0x just denotes that the characters after it represent a hex string.

```
0x1A == 1Ah == 26 == 1A
```

So the 0x is just to clarify what format the output is in, no need to worry about it.

Comment: Base 16 hexadecimal number https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61bl/r//cur/bits/decimal-binary-hex.html

Answer (score 107):

Here is my solution:

```
public static String encode(String key, String data) throws Exception {
  Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
  SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
  sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

  return Hex.encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
  System.out.println(encode("key", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));
}
```

Or you can return the hash encoded in Base64:

```
Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

The output in hex is as expected:

```
f7bc83f430538424b13298e6aa6fb143ef4d59a14946175997479dbc2d1a3cd8
```

Comment: You probably dont want to use `key.getBytes()` instead it would be prudent to specify the encoding i.e. `key.getBytes("UTF-8")` else you may fine yourself with runtime specific bugs :)

Comment: `Hex` is not available in native android API now any alternative for it?

Comment: On non-Android, can use [javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html). Alternatively see custom implementation in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java

Comment: Where does the Hex class come from? What is the import?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encodeHexString(byte[])

Comment: as of apache commons codec 1.10, this throws `NoSuchMethodError` for `Hex.encodeHexString()`. @Bikesh's suggestion works: `new String(Hex.encodeHex(...))`

Comment: to @Dori 's point, I had to use `key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and `data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to avoid throwing an `UnsupportedEncodingException`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html

Comment: If you don't have access to Hex, you can do this for example;
byte[] hashBytes = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : hashBytes) sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));

Answer (score 26):

If you're using Guava, its latest release now lets you use

```
 Hashing.hmacSha256()
```

One example of using this:

```
String hash = Hashing.hmacSha256("mykey".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).hashString("my_message", StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString()
```

Further documentation here:  https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html#hmacSha256-byte:A-

Comment: Can you expand upon this? I'd like to see more detail, assuming `String message` and `String secret`.

Comment: @Tony example added!

Answer (score 14):

The answer that you got there is correct. One minor thing in the code above, you need to init(key) before you can call doFinal()

```
    final Charset charSet = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
    final Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");

    final SecretKeySpec secret_key = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(charSet.encode("key").array(), "HmacSHA256");
    try {
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 13):

This is working fine for me

I have add dependency

```
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
```

ref: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9

my function

```
public String encode(String key, String data) {
    try {

        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

        return Hex.encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Actually this one is the simplest working solution that also nicely handles all possible exceptions.

Comment: @tom how does it handle any exceptions? It prints a stack trace in case of an exception and makes them disappear silently.

Comment: sorry, wrong phrasing, I meant it shows which exceptions can occur during the procedure you have to handle.

Answer (score 9):

## Try this

Sorry for being late, I have tried all above answers but none of them is giving me correct value, After doing the lot of R&D I have found a simple way that gives me exact value.

1. Declare this method in your class

   ```
   private String hmacSha(String KEY, String VALUE, String SHA_TYPE) {
   try {
       SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"), SHA_TYPE);
       Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(SHA_TYPE);
       mac.init(signingKey);
       byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(VALUE.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       byte[] hexArray = {(byte)'0', (byte)'1', (byte)'2', (byte)'3', (byte)'4', (byte)'5', (byte)'6', (byte)'7', (byte)'8', (byte)'9', (byte)'a', (byte)'b', (byte)'c', (byte)'d', (byte)'e', (byte)'f'};
       byte[] hexChars = new byte[rawHmac.length * 2];
       for ( int j = 0; j < rawHmac.length; j++ ) {
           int v = rawHmac[j] & 0xFF;
           hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
           hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
       }
       return new String(hexChars);
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       throw new RuntimeException(ex);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Use this like

   ```
   Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: "+hmacSha("key","text","HmacSHA256"));
   ```

**Verification**

1.Android studio output
[image: Android studio output]
2. Online HMAC generator Output(Visit [here](https://codebeautify.org/hmac-generator) for Online Genrator)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Java simple code to generate encoded(HMAC-x) signatures.** *(Tried using Java-8 and Eclipse)*

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

/**
 * Encryption class to show how to generate encoded(HMAC-x) signatures.
 * 
 */
public class Encryption {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String message = "This is my message.";
        String key = "your_key";
        String algorithm = "HmacMD5";  // OPTIONS= HmacSHA512, HmacSHA256, HmacSHA1, HmacMD5

        try {

            // 1. Get an algorithm instance.
            Mac sha256_hmac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);

            // 2. Create secret key.
            SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), algorithm);

            // 3. Assign secret key algorithm.
            sha256_hmac.init(secret_key);

            // 4. Generate Base64 encoded cipher string.
            String hash = Base64.encode(sha256_hmac.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8")));

            // You can use any other encoding format to get hash text in that encoding.
            System.out.println(hash);

            /**
             * Here are the outputs for given algorithms:-
             * 
             * HmacMD5 = hpytHW6XebJ/hNyJeX/A2w==
             * HmacSHA1 = CZbtauhnzKs+UkBmdC1ssoEqdOw=
             * HmacSHA256 =gCZJBUrp45o+Z5REzMwyJrdbRj8Rvfoy33ULZ1bySXM=
             * HmacSHA512 = OAqi5yEbt2lkwDuFlO6/4UU6XmU2JEDuZn6+1pY4xLAq/JJGSNfSy1if499coG1K2Nqz/yyAMKPIx9C91uLj+w==
             */

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

> NOTE: You can use any other Algorithms and can try generating `HmacMD5`, `HmacSHA1`, `HmacSHA256`, `HmacSHA512` signatures.

Answer (score 2):

If but any chance you found a solution how to calculate HMAC-SHA256 here, but you're getting an exception like this one:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   encodeHexString([B)Ljava/lang/String; in class
>   Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' appears in
>   /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)

Then use:

```
public static String encode(String key, String data) {
    try {
        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
        hmac.init(secret_key);
        return new String(Hex.encodeHex(hmac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
public String HMAC_SHA256(String secret, String message)
{
    String hash="";
    try{
        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

        hash = Base64.encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return hash.trim();
}
```